# "Consult" with non-living

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

Can we use the word **consult** with unanimated objects.

- You need to consult a dictionary
- Please consult the works of Douglas Howard before trying it out
- One should consult the book by Adam Fist before making such suggestions

Comment: The action in "consult" refers to the subject (you, one, etc.) which are animate. What you are asking about is "The dictionary consulted me." Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

In your use of

> consult

it has the meaning of

> look up
>   refer to
>   checkout

In your example,

> I don't know the meaning of that word, I will have to **consult** my dictionary.

is appropriate and understandable usage but a formalistic/stuffy way of expressing

> I don't know the meaning of that word, I will have to **look it up** in my dictionary.

Comment: So **consult** is possible but formal?

Comment: To me, **consult** sounds more formal the alternatives, as in "Allow me to **consult** my dictionary." instead of "I need **to look that up**."